# How do I get my JQuery script to work in HTML - Table

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm very new to programming guys!
I have some JQuery script that create a popout box. I want this to run when an image in my HTML is clicked. I have linked the script at the top of my html file and the files are stored in my root, I just need to tell the table to read the JQuery now right?

My JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" />

    <!-- Example script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#basic_button").click( function() {
            jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert  box');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input id="basic_button" type="button" value="Show Basic Alert" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My HTML table code with images in:

```
<tr> 
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25prism.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25dbk.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25premium.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g12.jpg" title=""></td>
</tr>
```

How do I do this? thanks :)

Comment: `I want this to run when an image in my HTML is clicked.` Well, bind the event to your images instead of your `#basic_button` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the script below it should do what you want. I've included a standard alert because I'm not sure what JAlert() is. Instead i've included a regular alert() also.

To explain what the script does, on page load **$(function()){}** we tell the page to listen for a "click" event on the "Image element". To tell the script what image we want we add an arbitrary new class to called "clickable" (but you can call it whatever you want) we use this class to find the element we want to attach the event to.

Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $(".clickable").on('click',function(){
                        jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert  box'); // Don't know what JAlert is might require you to include some extra library
                        alert("I clicked on "+$(this).attr("src"));
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <tr>
                <td><img class="clickable" alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25prism.jpg" title=""></td>
                <td><img class="clickable" alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25dbk.jpg" title=""></td>
                <td><img class="clickable" alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25.jpg" title=""></td>
                <td><img class="clickable" alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25premium.jpg" title=""></td>
                <td><img class="clickable" alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g12.jpg" title=""></td>
            </tr>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Should this code work straight away? I copied the code and added the class to the images but nothing happened? I'm very new to code so I struggle with simple things

Comment: I edited the answer so you can cut and paste and it should work.

Comment: Keep in mind that "JAlert" sounds like you might be using a light box plug-in. If that's the case you'll need to make sure you include the scripts that plugin uses (http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/) If you just want to see it work I would recommend using a standard alert() until you get more familiar with JS.

Comment: Can i get rid of the JAlert? All i want is a pop-up box to appear when my image is clicked... one that supports images and text. previous I was using an onclick=alert.. but images can't be used. Any alternatives? Im a noob

Comment: I can see it working in the JsFiddle - so something must be counter-acting the code... not sure why its not working >:(

Comment: Yes there are many alternatives.(and everyone was a noob at some point :) If you're just looking for a simple dialog then you can use something like this. (http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) It's super simple and light weight

Comment: My suggestion would be to start with a clean HTML document. Don't try to hack it in.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to put your Javascript code at the bottom of your page.

Then, note that `#basic_button` is a reference of the `<input id="basic_button" />`. You need to replace this reference of one reference of your table. In your example `td img` is good enoght, but I recommend you to put a class in your table and use it.

For example, It should works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" />

    <!-- Example script -->
</head>
<body>
  <table class="some-class">
    <tr> 
      <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25prism.jpg" title=""></td>
      <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25dbk.jpg" title=""></td>
      <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25.jpg" title=""></td>
      <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25premium.jpg" title=""></td>
      <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g12.jpg" title=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".some-class td img").click( function() {
            jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert  box');
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the link to jQuery at the bottom of your html file.
The page loads quicker and scripts and dependancies execute without problems if implementet the right way.

```html
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plug…-->
  <script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("td>img").on("click", function() {
    alert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert  box');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input id="basic_button" type="button" value="I am useless" />
    </p>
  <table>
  <tr> 
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25prism.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25dbk.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g25premium.jpg" title=""></td>
    <td><img alt="TE37" src="images/showroom/g12.jpg" title=""></td>
</tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You must set the event not to your button, on the contrary on table cells or on the images in your cells

The example below works when you click on an image contained by a cell:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
  $("td>img").on("click", function() {
    jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert  box');
  });
});
```